# How to redirect update site url in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-emf, p2

I am now distributing the plugin from the Eclipse Update Site.

An example address is as follows.

foo.com/update/1.0

I would like to change this address to:

foo.com/update/foo/1.0

Even if people who have already installed the plugin enter only the first address
I want to be redirected so that I can download the plugin from the second URL.

What should I do?

Comment: Sounds like something you would have to do with redirection on the web server.

Comment: @greg-449 umm.. Are you sure? When I tried, there was no response. Maybe it has something to do with the p2 repository?